# Add buffered image on an existing Image Icon

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I build a game in which I want to add a buffered image on existing background image icon, My code is for this game is:

```
public class Hunter extends JFrame {
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("F:\\workspace\\HunterGame\\src\\huntergame\\background.jpg"));
BufferedImage image;
Graphics g;
Hunter(){
    setSize(961, 694);
    setResizable(false);
    setTitle("Hunter");
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    this.setLocation(dim.width/2-this.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-this.getSize().height/2);
    panel.add(label);
    add(panel);

    addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
            int x = me.getX();
            int y = me.getY();

            if((x>11&&x<69)&&(y>26&&y<69)){
                dispose();
                new menu();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
        }
    });



   try {                
      image = ImageIO.read(new File("F:\\workspace\\HunterGame\\src\\huntergame\\hunter.png"));
   } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception Occurs");
   }
   JLabel label1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
   label.add(label1);

   revalidate();
}
}
```

I also tried `Graphics.drawImage()` method but this didn't work.
My background image is on JLabel and label is on frame and for second image label1 is on label but I also tried this on JPanel and no result showing.
Output Screen show only background image.
Please help me out in this.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a second label to the background label then you need to set the layout manager of the label.

The basic code would be something like:

```
JLabel background = new JLabel(....);
background.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );

JLabel foreground = new JLabel(...);
background.add( foreground );

frame.add(background, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible( true );
```